# how do i know ObjectAnimator has runned?

Tags: android, objectanimator

I put three `ObjectAnimator` into `AnimatorSet` ,when I cancel `AnimatorSet` or `AnimatorSet` finishes ,i need record the `getAnimatedValue` . But when I cancel the `AnimatorSet`, a `ObjectAnimator` maybe not had runned and i can call `isRunning` in `onAnimationCancel` but how do I judge this `ObjectAnimator` had runned at `onAnimationEnd` .

```
animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mSunMovPos = (float) sunAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                mCurSunSetColor = (int) sunSetAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                //How do judge nightAnimator had runned ?
                mCurNightColor = (int) nightAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mSunMovPos = (float) sunAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                mCurSunSetColor = (int) sunSetAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                if (nightAnimator.isRunning())
                    mCurNightColor = (int) nightAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: you can use `isStarted()` and `isRunning()` so you can find out three different states of your animation: a) not started b) still running c) has ended

Comment: No ,you cannot ,because `isStarted ` means `the Animator has been started and not yet ended` and `isRunning ` means `this Animator is currently running` . But the `Animator` had been ended in `onAnimationEnd ` . So it cann't use both them.

Comment: so what actually do you want to achieve? maybe i got you wrong

Comment: Because i execute `animatorSet.play(sunAnimator).with(sunSetAnimator).before(nightAnimator)` , the `nightAnimator` maybe not execute when I cancel `animatorSet` . In this condition , i need know whether the `nightAnimator` starts run in `onAnimationEnd `.